# PZEM-004T can't read current

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, current, voltage

I'm trying to measure the current, voltage, and power of AC load using Peacefair PZEM-004Tv3.0 module. For the serial communication of this module, I'm using SoftwareSerial Pins 2 and 3 on Arduino Uno.
But this module seems doesn't work well, it just read the voltage and the rest is zero. The datasheet said:

- current test value is from the beginning of 0.02A
- power test value is from the beginning of 0.4W

I have assumed the load that I'm trying to measure hasn't enough minimum current or power. But I have tried to measure a bigger load also, and the result of current and power measurement is still zero.

I don't think it is caused by the program because I just run the example of the library. I'm using [this](https://github.com/mandulaj/PZEM-004T-v30) library.

Here I attached how do I wire my pieces stuff:
[image: picture]

Any suggestions?

Comment: SoftwareSerial doesn't work well at 115200 baud on the 8 bit Arduinos. They can't keep up with the flow of data.

Comment: Have you tried placing the sensor over the other AC load wire?

Comment: Uhh, are you running the line and return through the same CT and going in opposite directions?

Comment: I created an answer thinking that it was.  For anyone that doesn't see it, if you zoom in your can just barely tell that the black wire is in fact *outside* the CT.

Comment: It should always be on one lead, not both, and I could see the black is outside. What I suggested is placing the sensor on the "other" lead, meaning remove the red and try the black. Also, have you tried reducing the speed to 9600 as Majenko suggested?

Comment: @Nino, to be clear, none of what I wrote was addressing your suggestion.

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions but it still doesn't work guys :(

Comment: just changed the CT with the new one and now everything works fine, thank you :D

Comment: It would probably be best to delete the question.